# Image in Flutter streched FittedBox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i m a beginner to flutter and I was trying to Implement some image inside a Container in my app.
Here is my code :

```
                   Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/' + i.toString() + ".jpg"),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

My image showed up and it did filled the Container , but it looks horrible . It is super stretched , I tried changing the fit: BoxFit to something like `fit : BoxFit.contain` but it won't work.

Here is how my UI Looks :
[The picture (Display properly but just stretched)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PSI2.png)

How do I make this image fit without stretching it.

Any answer would be appreciated , and thanks for helping.

Comment: try BoxFit.fitWidth or BoxFit.fitHeight in Image.assets directly don't use FitterBox(remove it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use Boxfit.fill, the image will take up the complete space of parent container. Aspect ratio here would be secondary. That is why the image looks stretched.

Try Boxfit.cover. Another option would be to equal Container width to double.infinity and adjust the height, as needed.

Answer (score 0):

BoxFit.fill will stretch the image to fill the space.
You should use `BoxFit.cover` to fill the space without stretching the image.

If you want to make sure the full width of the image is visible, use `BoxFit.fitWidth`.

If you want to make sure the full height of the image is visible, use `BoxFit.fitHeight`.